# Using Advanced Custom Fields (Wordpress) to show 3 images per list item in Flexslider

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I am  building a Wordpress slideshow using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and Flexslider in the Bootstrap framework. My goal is to show the content of 3 posts in one list-item so that the flexslider displays the 3 images as one slide. The code I have right now displays 3 images in one slide, but it's the same image repeated 3 times. I'm so close, but I can't quite figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
<?php while(the_flexible_field("slideshow")): ?>
        <?php if(get_row_layout() == "new_slide"): ?>
            <li>
            <?php while(get_row_layout() == "new_slide"): $count++;?>
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('slide_image'), 'large'); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php  the_sub_field('slide_heading');?>" class="rotate"/>
                    <?php if($count==3) break; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </li> 
            <li><a href="<?php echo the_sub_field('slide_link');?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php  the_sub_field('slide_heading');?>" class="rotate"/></a>
                <div class="container homeslide">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <div class="flex-caption"><h4><?php echo the_sub_field('slide_heading');?></h4><?php echo the_sub_field('slide_description');?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>  
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the same index every time (`$image[0];`) it should be `$image[$count]`. Each post attachment is stored in another index. So if you keep asking for index 0, you will keep getting the same image.